# SQL select / join performace (PHP, PDO)

Tags: sql, select, join

What is the most **efficient** way to get data from two tables set up in the following way:

### Table 1:

```
ID(PK)  |  Name  |  Age
--------------------------
 1      |  Jim   |  44
 2      |  Jane  |  35
 3      |  John  |  22
```

### Table 2

```
Name(PK)  |  Pet(PK)
-----------------
Jim       |  Cat
Jim       |  Dog
Jane      |  Fish
```

There is a constraint on "Name" with the FK in Table 2

### Results

**I want the age and all the pets for a specific person.**

```
Name  |  Age  |  Pet
---------------------
Jim   |  44   |  Cat
Jim   |  44   |  Dog
```

As I see it these are my options:

1) Left join table 2 on Name and end up with redundant data in my resulting array for Name and Age (as above).

2) Use a function that turns the pets into a comma separated list.

3) Use 2 separate selects.

My question is relating to performance of the 3 options above. I don't need SQL (specifically, unless you want to suggest another method).

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with performance. Choose the one you like more (presumably it's the first)

Comment: what storage engine? is it even MySQL? Where is the server? Where is the PHP server? How much memory/hdd space/etc? What's the bandwidth between the two? If it's the same server, what else is on it? How many rows are there? How many other tables? How often is the data accessed? ... Efficiency has more to do than just the SQL query... you have to give us more to go on.  Chances are your PHP code is in more need of performance tuning than the SQL query

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So they are all equally as efficient in terms of SQL? @cegfault MySQL / MyISAM. Some 40+ additional fields being selected in table 1 and 2. Typically 30 rows returned for T1 and up to 150 for T2 per query. Approx 10 users co-currently querying every 5 secs or so, increasing with time. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
  select 
  tb01.name, tb01.age, tb02.pet
  from 
  table01 tb01
  left join table02 tb02 on tb02.name = tb01.name
```

Comment: Why is this the most efficient as requested by the OP?